# Angular 5 - I retrieve my object from firestore in ngOnInit but my view won't update

Tags: angular, angular5

Using Angular 5 and firestore. I successfully retrieve my document and can see it when I console.log(this.assets) in ngOnInit(). The weird thing is that when my site reloads, if I am quick to get to the view *before* the console.log() runs, my view renders correctly. But if I wait until I see the console.log(), then click on the link to my view, the view won't load the object that I can see clearly in the console.log(). I assume that my view is not refreshing after: `this.assets = assets;`

assets.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../services/data.service';
import {Asset} from '../models/data.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-assets',
  templateUrl: './assets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./assets.component.css']
})
export class AssetsComponent implements OnInit {
  assets: Asset[];
  loadCompleted: boolean = false;
  constructor(public data: DataService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCompleted = false;
    this.data.getAssets().subscribe(
      (assets)=>{
        this.assets = assets;
        console.log("assets.component init")
        console.log(assets);
        console.log(assets.length);
        console.log('2', this.loadCompleted)
      }, 
      (error)=> console.log(error),
      ()=>{
        this.loadCompleted = true
        console.log("3",this.loadCompleted)
      }
    )

  }

}
```

Those console.log()'s show the correct object and object.length>0. (there are 4 objects in my database)

assets.component.html:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    TEST TEST TEST
    <div *ngIf="loadCompleted">
        <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let asset of assets">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              {{asset.name}}
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

navbar with /assets link

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <a routerLink="/home"  class="navbar-brand">Finances</a>
  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-outline-primary navbar-toggler" 
          (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" 
          aria-controls="collapseMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="collapseMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" *ngIf="af.isLoggedIn">
          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a routerLink="/home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li class="navbar-item">
              <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                <button class="btn btn-dark nav-link" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Assets</button>
                <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                  <button class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/assets" >Home</button>
                  <button class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/addAsset" >Add Asset</button>
                  <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
                </div>
              </div>
          </li>

          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a routerLink="/liabilities" class="nav-link">Liabilities</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Income</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Expenses</a>
          </li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="navbar-item" *ngIf="af.isLoggedIn" >
            <a routerLink="/profile" class="nav-link">{{af.user_displayName || af.user_email}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-item" *ngIf="af.isLoggedIn" >
            <a routerLink="/profile" class="nav-link">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-item" >
          <a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link" *ngIf="!af.isLoggedIn">Login/Signup</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link" (click)="logout($event)" *ngIf="af.isLoggedIn">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

app-router.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {AssetsComponent} from './assets/assets.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {ProfileComponent} from './profile/profile.component';
import { AssetsAddAssetComponent} from './assets-add-asset/assets-add-asset.component';
import { LiabilitiesComponent} from './liabilities/liabilities.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'assets', component: AssetsComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
  {path: 'liabilities', component: LiabilitiesComponent},
  {path: 'addAsset', component: AssetsAddAssetComponent},
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/observable';

import {Asset} from '../models/data.model';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  assetCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Asset>;
  assets: Observable<Asset[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    //this.assets = this.afs.collection('assets').valueChanges();
    this.assets = this.afs.collection('assets').snapshotChanges().map(changes=>{
      return changes.map(a=>{
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Asset;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      })
    })
  }

  getAssets(){
    return this.assets;
  }

  addAsset(asset: Asset){
    this.afs.collection('assets').add(asset);
  }

}
```

Asset Interface:

```
export interface Asset {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    value?: number;
  }
```

Comment: The problem, as you describe it, happens when clicking on a link to some view. But there is no link at all in the code you posted. And you also seem to talk about two components and two views, but you posted only one.

Comment: When I restart with ng serve, my app starts at '/home', then I click my link to go to '/assets' and it goes to the view for that page. The link works fine and loads whatever HTML is in there. See my edit: the  "TEST TEST TEST" loads. So my view is loading, but for some reason has no access to the assets object if I wait until after the console.log() runs. ie after the ngOnInit runs. 

If I quickly click on my "/assets" link however, the view loads correctly and has access to assets object. There is only one view, and one component: assets.component.ts and .html (edited)

Comment: So, you're saying that the same component (assets) displays a list if you click "quickly" on the link from home that goes to that component, but doesn't if you click "slowly" on that same link? How could there be only one view and one component if it starts at /home, containing a link that goes to another component? Post all the relevant code.

Comment: Ok, i think all relevant code is in there. I changed a few things. Have a look at my new ngOnInit in assets.component.ts. In the subscribe method, the third function, the "complete" function, does not run for some reason. Maybe that's part of the problem? Doesn't explain why I can see the object though in the console.log() above. Thanks for your help and time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an old-fashioned RxJS problem. Your `getAssets()` call returns an observable -- `this.assets`. Since `this.assets` is in a singleton service (will only be initialized once) events *will not* be duplicated for each new subscriber. In other words, if when you browse to your new page `this.assets` has already been subscribed too, the second subscriber will not receive any events.

Fortunately this is easy to fix.

```
this.assets = this.afs.collection('assets').snapshotChanges().map(changes=>{
  return changes.map(a=>{
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Asset;
    data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return data;
  })
})
// This will cache the last value and reemit it to new subscribers
.publishReplay(1)
.refCount();
```

Depending on your version of RX, another option would be to use a `ReplaySubject`.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  assetCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Asset>;
  // Will automatically cache the last event for you.
  assets = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    //this.assets = this.afs.collection('assets').valueChanges();
    this.afs.collection('assets').snapshotChanges().map(changes=>{
      return changes.map(a=>{
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Asset;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      })
    }).subscribe(data => {
       this.assets.next(data);
    })
  }

  getAssets(){
    return this.assets;
  }

  addAsset(asset: Asset){
    this.afs.collection('assets').add(asset);
  }

}
```

Comment: Used the first option and it worked! Also had to: 

import 'rxjs/add/operator/publishReplay';

Comment: Cheers! Sorry I forget to include the import.